# Android Activity Recognition not working with Nexus 5

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I had a code working that was using Google's Activity Recognition Updates. Now all of a sudden these seem to send updates either several times per second or never although requested every 20 seconds. I haven't changed the code and checked earlier versions but got the same problem.

I built a minimal example from the tutorial but also get no activity updates with my Nexus 5 device. With my HTC Desire (MildWild 5.0 based on Android 2.3.7) it works perfectly fine. I suspected Google Play Services but both phones have version 4.2.43 installed

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.testactivities;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    // Constants that define the activity detection interval
    public static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    public static final int DETECTION_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 1;
    public static final int DETECTION_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS = 
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * DETECTION_INTERVAL_SECONDS;
    /*
     * Store the PendingIntent used to send activity recognition events
     * back to the app
     */
    private PendingIntent mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent;
    // Store the current activity recognition client
    private ActivityRecognitionClient mActivityRecognitionClient;
    // Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
    private boolean mInProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*
         * Instantiate a new activity recognition client. Since the
         * parent Activity implements the connection listener and
         * connection failure listener, the constructor uses "this"
         * to specify the values of those parameters.
         */
        mActivityRecognitionClient =
                new ActivityRecognitionClient(this, this, this);
        /*
         * Create the PendingIntent that Location Services uses
         * to send activity recognition updates back to this app.
         */
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                this.getApplicationContext(), ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
        /*
         * Return a PendingIntent that starts the IntentService.
         */
        mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Start with the request flag set to false
        mInProgress = false;
        this.startUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Request activity recognition updates based on the current
     * detection interval.
     *
     */
     public void startUpdates() {
        // If a request is not already underway
        if (!mInProgress) {
            // Indicate that a request is in progress
            mInProgress = true;
            // Request a connection to Location Services
            mActivityRecognitionClient.connect();
        //
        } else {
            /*
             * A request is already underway. You can handle
             * this situation by disconnecting the client,
             * re-setting the flag, and then re-trying the
             * request.
             */
        }
    }

     /*
      * Called by Location Services once the location client is connected.
      *
      * Continue by requesting activity updates.
      */
     @Override
     public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
         Log.v("EXAMPLE","connected");
         /*
          * Request activity recognition updates using the preset
          * detection interval and PendingIntent. This call is
          * synchronous.
          */
         mActivityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(
                 DETECTION_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS,
                 mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
         /*
          * Since the preceding call is synchronous, turn off the
          * in progress flag and disconnect the client
          */
         mInProgress = false;
         mActivityRecognitionClient.disconnect();
     }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        Log.v("EXAMPLE","Connection failed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.v("EXAMPLE","Disconnected");
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testactivities"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testactivities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.testactivities.ActivityRecognitionIntentService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

RecognitionIntentService:

```
package com.example.testactivities;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ActivityRecognitionIntentService extends IntentService {

    public ActivityRecognitionIntentService() {
        super("ActivityRecognitionIntent");
        Log.v("EXAMPLE","constructor");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v("EXAMPLE","new activity update");
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I believe canopi identified the correct problem. When the device is still with high confidence, it doesn't fire recognition intents at all. This was definitely different a year ago (on other devices). To detect if the device is still I log the last incoming activity with its timestamp and check periodically for that. An old timestamp signals that the device has been still for that time.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. What i noticed is that after i call disconnect on the ActivityRecognitionClient it will never fire the onDisconnected callback. That seems to be the culprit because i had this working for an hour or so and updates started to come in as soon as the disconnect was finished.

Comment: Good to hear that someone is having the same issue. I will check on the onDisconnected callback. I think that didn't fire either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you increase the detection interval, it takes at least 6 to 7 seconds for the sensors to detect a change in your activity. Also, I have observed that ActivityRecognition stops firing intents if the device is Still for a certain period of time. They are immediately triggered when the device is in motion again.

Comment: It should fire when the activity changes so that it stops firing when lying still for long periods does not worry me. The detection interval is definitely not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have the location services disabled on your Nexus 5 device...
Activity Recognition needs the location services active/enabled.

Comment: Thanks for answering although the thread is old. I updated my question and marked canopi's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by canopi, increase the detection 'time', in which 0 will give you the fastest result.

I had encountered the same problem and instead of adding the build() part on onCreate directly, I added the method below and called it on onCreate(). Try to trace the code from this [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/ActivityRecognition/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/activityrecognition/MainActivity.java). I got the code stripped down from there.

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .build();
}
```

Also add `buildGoogleApiClient()` to your onCreate method.