# locationClient.requestLocationUpdates doesn't fires Pending Intent in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a code that works fine in Android 4.3 and below. But the same code doesn't work in 4.4 android. Please help if anyone knows about the issue.

Below is the code,

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    Log.i(TAG, "location client connected");
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(2 * 60 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1 *60 * 1000);

    mIntentService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, mIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mPendingIntent);
}
```

Below is my Service class,

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Context context;

    public MyService () {
        super("MyService ");
        context = this;
    }

    public MyService (String name) {
        super("MyService ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // my code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately I updated the `google-play-service_lib`

and changed the `locationClient.requestLocationUpdates` method to `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, mPendingIntent);`

Now everything seems working fine on all versions.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem only with Nexus 5. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352134/android-activity-recognition-not-working-with-nexus-5)
No answers yet, though. I tried changing FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT as suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61850). That did not solve it either.

Comment: I too still haven't found any working solution. Currently what I'm doing is, if my Service is not invoked through LocationClient, I start my custom service to read location using AlarmManager.

Comment: In case you didn't found any solution yet, please see my answer.